# An intuitive reason why the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(\pi_n)$ might be positive where $\pi_n$ is the n-th digit of $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, recreational-mathematics, irrational-numbers, pi

Let $\pi_n$ be the $n-th$ digit in the base ten decimal representation of $\pi$. Is there an intuitive reason why it might be true $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(\pi_n)>0$$ For short handedness I write $\gamma = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(\pi_n)$. Over the first 480,000 digits of $\pi$ I have that $\gamma \approx 20,000$. Surely $0 \leq \pi_n \leq 9$ and $\cos(\pi_n)<0$ if $\pi_n$ is one of $2,3,4,8\text{ or }9.$ The big jumps in the sum occur whenever $\pi_n=0$ in which case $\cos(\pi_n)=1$. It's a reach for me but I cannot think of a reason why this sum might be positive or negative. I am not able to compute this sum for the first 1,000,000 digits of $\pi$ so I am not certain that $\gamma$ "turns" back to negative. Moreover I am not sure if it is true $\gamma \neq 0$.  This is just pure curiosity and fun with the digits of $\pi$.

Comment: Is there a proof that the sum converges ?

Comment: If the sum diverges to infinty, are you still writing that it is $>0$?

Comment: Andre S. I suspect no and I never thought of that. Is there a reason to suspect that at arbitrarily large values of $n$ the finite sum might be negative ?

Comment: For all we know, all digits of $\pi$ after position $10^{20}$ may be $2$, $3$ or $4$ ...

Comment: The series diverges since there is some $m\in \{0,1,\dots ,9\}$ such that  $\pi_n=m$ for infinitely many $n,$ proving $\cos (\pi_n)$ does not converge to $0.$

Answer (score 6):

Averaging over the digits $\{0\ldots9\}$, the value $\cos(\pi_n)$ is on average larger than zero, at $\approx0.042$. If $\pi$ is even close to being a normal number (and there is currently no evidence to suppose otherwise), you would expect that the sum over the first $480,000$ digits would be around $480,000\times0.042 \approx20160$, which is pretty close to what you got.

Of course, it's still entirely possible that $\pi$ becomes a long stream of $3$'s at some point, and your sum will be negative - but to the best of my knowledge, we [just don't know](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23551/23319).

Comment: The actual sum I have is $20,680.311216004\ldots $

Comment: Using your reasoning at $1,000$ we expect $\gamma=42$ but it is closer to $29$. At $2,000$ we expect $\gamma=84$ but it's actual sum is closer to $71$.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez - If $\pi$ is normal, it doesn't say that the digits are uniformly distributed on any interval, just that on average they are. The more digits you sum, the closer you'd expect the numbers to match up.

Comment: Selecting a random number uniformly from $\{\cos 0,\cos 1,\dots,\cos 9\}$ has a variance of roughly [0.52768](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=variance+of+%7Bcos+0,+cos+1,+cos+2,+cos+3,+cos+4,+cos+5,+cos+6,+cos+7,+cos+8,+cos+9%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22variance%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22PopulationVariance%22%7D&rawformassumption=%22TrigRD%22+-%3E+%22R%22). So, if $\pi$ is normal, the error in this estimate after $d$ digits should be on the order of $\sqrt{0.52768d}$. When $d=1000$, this is roughly 23; when $d=2000$, it's roughly 32; when $d=480000$, it's roughly 503.

Comment: In all three cases, the error in the estimate is of the size you'd expect (assuming $\pi$ is normal).